# Java selenium questions

Tags: java, selenium

What I'm wanting to do is read each line and make it input into email, it does that once, when I try to "refresh" the page to clear the text boxs I get an error.

```
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("emails.txt"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            driver.get("https://signup.live.com/signup?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=12&ct=1465840004&rver=6.7.6643.0&wp=&wreply=https%3a%2f%2fwww.msn.com%2fen-us%2fhomepage%2fSecure%2fPassport%3fru%3dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww.msn.com%252f%253focid%253dmailsignout%2526pfr%253d1&id=1184&pcexp=True&bk=1465840005&uiflavor=web&uaid=dc151162984741948b8371ce3e0c865e&mkt=EN-US&lc=1033&lic=1");
            Thread.sleep(650);
            Email.sendKeys(line);
            Refresher.click();
            Thread.sleep(650);
            if (TakenErrorMsg.isDisplayed()){
                System.out.println(line + " is taken!");

            }else{
                System.out.println(line + " is not taken!");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is the error, i'm pretty new so if anyone could show me how to "read" this it would be very helpful.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=51.0.2704.103)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-VOA61U9', ip: '192.168.0.2', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_73'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4), userDataDir=C:\Users\Skid\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir20756_575}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=51.0.2704.103, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: b48d6cc33021d97d8a72976ad4d033b7
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:122)
    at tuna.tuna(tuna.java:28)
    at main$1.actionPerformed(main.java:37)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the exception log, the first line tells you what went wrong:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

This is telling you that selenium threw a StaleElementReferenceException, if you google it, you will get to this selenium documentation page ([link](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp)). Which basically it explains you that the element you are trying to reach through selenium is not longer in the DOM.

This is happening because you are reloading the page several times, you would need to refresh the instances of your elements on each page load, the elements that you need to reload the reference is:

- Email
- Refresher
- TakenErrorMsg

Answer (score 0):

Stale Element Reference error is coming because you are trying to access an element which is no longer present in the DOM.

So If you want to access that element there are four ways to access it

1. use wait method to wait for the element to present
2. Check the element present or visibility by *isDispayed()* & *isEnabled()* before performing any action
3. Create a *Class* which search the stale element if it is not available to search again it in DOM

   public class SearchStaleWebElement implements WebElement {
       private WebElement element;
       private final WebDriver driver;
       private final By foundBy;

   ```
   public NeverStaleWebElement(WebElement element, WebDriver driver, By foundBy) {
       this.element = element;
       this.driver = driver;
       this.foundBy = foundBy;
   }

   @Override
   public void click() {
       try {
           element.click();
       } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
           // log exception

           // assumes implicit wait, use custom findElement() methods for custom behaviour
           element = driver.findElement(foundBy);

           // recursion, consider a conditioned loop instead
           click();
       }
   }

   // ... similar for other methods, too
   ```

   }

You can create as more method as your requirement.